# How to build OpenCV_FFMPEG.dll?

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg

I have been trying to figure out a way to build OpenCV_FFMPEG.dll on my own. This is necessary to customize the FFMPEG build according to my requirements rather than going with FFMPEG library(OpenCV_FFMpeg) downloaded by OpenCV.

The closest post I found which tried explaining how to build OpenCV_FFMPEF.dll was this:
http://answers.opencv.org/question/124858/how-to-build-opencv_ffmpegdll-from-patched-ffmpeg-source/

Even that post is outdated and I get a plethora of linker errors and duplicate symbols when I followed the instructions.
Can anyhow help me how to build the library?

Comment: please specify your platform/OS/opencv version for building related errors.

Comment: I am trying to compile on Windows7 64bit OS. The OpenCV version is 3.4